# TypeError: setup() got multiple values for keyword argument 'packages'

Tags: python, setup.py

This error occurs on line 31 as noted below when I run the following command according to [these instructions](https://github.com/dwf/glmnet-python). How am I getting multiple values for `packages`?

```
python setup.py config_fc --fcompiler=gnu95 \
         --f77flags='-fdefault-real-8' \
         --f90flags='-fdefault-real-8' build
```

.

```
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
from numpy.distutils.system_info import get_info
import os, sys

import sys

fflags= '-fdefault-real-8 -ffixed-form'

# TODO: Fix it so that these flags are default.

config = Configuration(
    'glmnet',
    parent_package=None,
    top_path=None
)


f_sources = ['glmnet/glmnet.pyf','glmnet/glmnet.f']

config.add_extension(name='_glmnet',sources=f_sources)
config_dict = config.todict()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(version='1.1-5',
          description='Python wrappers for the GLMNET package',
          author='David Warde-Farley',
          author_email='dwf@cs.toronto.edu',
          url='github.com/dwf/glmnet-python',
          license='GPL2',
          requires=['NumPy (>= 1.3)'],
          packages=['glmnet'],            ### LINE 31
          **config_dict)
```

Comment: And what does `config_dict['packages']` contain? It could be that `glmnet` should just be added to that value..

Comment: `{'packages': ['glmnet'], 'name': 'glmnet', 'package_dir': {'glmnet': ''}}`

Comment: In that case you can omit the `packages` entry at line 31 altogether. The `Configuration` object provided that entry for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Configuration(package_name).to_dict()` result *already* includes the `packages=[package_name]` entry.

By including it in `setup()` *and* in the `config_dict` mapping, `setup()` is supplied that keyword twice. You could remove it from the `setup()` call (line 31):

```
setup(version='1.1-5',
      description='Python wrappers for the GLMNET package',
      author='David Warde-Farley',
      author_email='dwf@cs.toronto.edu',
      url='github.com/dwf/glmnet-python',
      license='GPL2',
      requires=['NumPy (>= 1.3)'],
      **config_dict)
```

I see that the author of the package [added the `packages` line explicitly 4 years ago](https://github.com/dwf/glmnet-python/commit/1c0e7eee40941db6acd9af126550d2774d308a6e); I strongly suspect that the NumPy behaviour has since changed.

You should probably file a [another issue](https://github.com/dwf/glmnet-python/issues) with the project.